# Couldn't deploy serverless lambda because of iam role issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I tried deploying my serverless framework via serverless deploy.
But it shows that user is not authorized to `iam:getRole`.
Where do I enable it? What all permission does the user need in aws for serverless deploy? I'm a poweruser, so I do have most of the permission. But still deployment failed with `iam:getRole` `iam:createRole`.

```
CREATE_FAILED: IamRoleLambdaExecution (AWS::IAM::Role)

Resource handler returned message: "User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:user/sai is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role teamize-dev-us-east-2-lambdaRole because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action (Service: Iam, Status Code: 403....
```

I tired giving fullLambda access, poweruser, apigateway fullaccess.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that `arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:user/sai` has the correct IAM permissions, specifically `GetRole`… From the exception is explicitly states you do not have that permission on the role. Make sure you look at the conditions in your role etc...

Comment: Where should I check this? In aws IAM console? If so, while checking the permission there isn't any iam:GetRole. Or should I mention anything in serverless.yaml file?

Comment: Yes, your user `sai` is missing the permissions.